# Noise Reduction

Tags: noise

The area where I live recently added 2 more lanes to the main road.  I am the first street in.  Even though I installed double pane windows throughout the entire house the noise at night especially is maddening.  This seems like such a complex issue, high frequencies, md frequencies, hollow doors, etc...I am open to suggestion.

Comment: How big is the street now, how much traffic, what kind of traffic (all cars, trucks, etc)? Did the new windows help at all, and if so how much?

Comment: Also related (among others): https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/soundproofing-a-room-from-outside-traffic-noise-and-vibrations?rq=1

Comment: The street was one lane going each direction.  It is now 2 lanes going each direction.  All types of traffic, cars, motorcycles, semis, trucks, etc...The thing is when I had the windows installed in 2014 the road had not been expanded yet.  I believe there surely is a difference from what it could have been but it is not enough.